What is the font used in this stenciled numbers from Evangelion?
I see this from many official merches of Evangelion ranging from PC brands like Asus, to apparels, to glasses.


Here's an example
Asus EVA 01 motherboard: (https://dlcdnwebimgs.asus.com/files/media/9DDA3BB7-F3A9-486C-9911-0C7268B0F610/v1/img/pic_dissipation.png)
Here's another from Asuka (EVA 02):(https://dlcdnwebimgs.asus.com/files/media/D35E4510-6019-4090-9676-6830AB80C4DB/v1/img/eva-2.png)
I've been searching everywhere to find the font used in both for the word "EVA" and the stenciled numbers

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you considered these might not be fonts you can just download? They could be custom designs. They could have been created using existing fonts which have been modified.  Logos often contain custom designed or modified letter forms.
